# MS ACCESS, VB Import External MS Access table into SQL server table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Database that is acting as a User Interface.
I have a linked SQL Server 2008 table in the Access Database.  On the user interface there are various filters/criteria that the user selects (such as date, external MS Access Database, etc.
These are all utilized in importing a database.  Right now I am importing the external MS Access database that the user selects into an internal table on the User Interface.
My goal is to import that data directly into a SQL server table.
Is this possible?

Here is how I am doing it now.

```
 Dim Select_File as string
 Dim varFile as Variant
 Dim DBMonth as String
 DBMonth = Me.Month.Value '<-- this is just the Month that is either Default to current month of what user selects in a combobox on user interface
 ' there is some code here that has the user select the external access database and varFile is = .SelectedItems
 Select_File = varFile     
 DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", Select_File, acTable, "Table_" & DBMonth & "_All", "Table"
```

So a table "Table" has the data from the external MS Access Database that user selected.
I am wondering if there is a simple way to import that data directly into SQL Server table.
I attempted to change the "Table" name to the linked SQL Server table but it just imports it into a local table named the same thing with a "_1" after it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want by executing an "append query".

I was unsure about the names, so in this example *[Table]* is the native Access table which contains the source data and *[SQL Server Table]* is a link to the destination table on the server.

```sql
INSERT INTO [SQL Server Table] (Fld1, Fld2, Fld3)
SELECT t.Fld1, t.Fld2, t.Fld3
FROM [Table] AS t
```